# Is it possible to remove all inter-tag spaces in an HTML string?

Tags: java, html-compression

I am using [htmlcompressor](https://code.google.com/archive/p/htmlcompressor/) lib.

The `compress` method does the job.

If the input is say `"<div>  \n\nhtml\n\n      </div>"`

It does convert the above to `"<div> html </div>"`

It still leaves at least single space around the tags. Is there a way, to say get rid of this with this lib. If not do we have a compressor that does a better job?

Comment: how about `"<div> html </div>".replaceAll(" ","");`

Comment: Jsoup has an astext or similar function